# What are the benefits of using Generics?

Tags: java, generics

I am new to Generics in Java. I have few doubts about the benefits of using Generics.
Please refer the below code -

```
<T extends Bounceable> void goGreen(T ob);

void goGreen(Bounceable ob);
```

Here Bounceable is an interface.

Can someone please explain me what is the difference in the above definitions. They both restrict the caller from passing an object to it which is not Bounceable type. If it is possible to implement the same code in interface style, then what is the benefit of using Generics? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question. I don't know the pros in using first notation.

Comment: Just because you can use generics, doesn't mean you should in all cases.  Generics can be over used like any feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are returning nothing like in your example, you haven't gained anything by using generics. The other declaration is just as useful.

On the other hand, generics allow you to create the following method:

```
<T extends Bounceable> T goGreen(T ob);
```

This returns an object of the same type as you pass in, which in a lot of scenarios save you a cast.
To quote @LuiggiMendoza's excellent example from the comments:
*Assume you have `Ball implements Bounceable` and `Cellphone implements Bounceable`. When you pass a `Ball` to this method, you expect the method to return a `Ball`, not a `Cellphone`.*

This is just not possible to achieve with the non-generic approach.

Comment: What about `Bounecable goGreen(Bounceable ob)`?

Comment: Thats the only benefit? Or there is anything else?

Comment: @VinceEmigh this isn't the same. The method means that you will pass and receive an instance of the class `T`. Assume you have `Ball implements Bounceable` and `Cellphone implements Bounceable`. When you pass a `Ball` to this method, you expect the method to return a `Ball`, not a `Cellphone`.

Comment: I understand it is not possible with the non-generic approach, but what is the advantage of it? How in your perception can I make the best use of Generics?

Comment: @AndreDuarte for OP's custom specific example, there's no other benefit. But note that this can be part of a fluent interface and builder pattern implementation.

Comment: ok @LuiggiMendoza, that is a good point. I will note it down.

Comment: Hi @LuiggiMendoza, can you mention few other areas where Generics could help me apart from the one my custom specific example?

Comment: @JavaManz if you're asking for generics in general, well then, the question may be closed as too broad. Study and learn of this feature in Java, then start coding and applying it where you think it may apply and learn with that practice. Note that there are lot of ways to use and overuse generics like writing your own custom framework for your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

What if you wanted it to return the same type it took in?

```
class Ball implements Bounceable{
   void throw(Object target){
      //impl
   }   
}

Bounceable goGreen(Bounceable ob);//returns a Bounceable back. no throw method

<T extends Bounceable> T goGreen(T ob);//returns a ball back when called with ball. I can throw it!
```

What if you wanted to restrict the types the other way?

```
<T super Bounceable> void setBounceableParent(T ob);//not possible with just polymorphism
```

What if you wanted a class that worked on a any type?

```
class Holder<T>{
   T data; 
   void put(T newData){
      data=newData;
   }
   T get(){//how do you make this type safe without generics or duck typing?
      return data;
   } 
}
```